# display all products in a single page (without using pager) ubercart

Tags: views, ubercart

I'm trying to display all products on a single page without a pager. Some sites have this functionality where you can click from page to page, or you can choose 'show all'. Or there is a drop down box where you can select how many products you want to view like this: http://www.newegg.com/Store/SubCategory.aspx?SubCategory=32&name=Laptops-Notebooks&Pagesize=100

Does ubercart have anything like this out of the box? I'm using the taxonomy_term views to display my categorized products right now. So for example, for a category:show, you can get there by going to: taxonomy/term/12 which I override to be category/shoe (with pathauto aliases).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Views module](https://drupal.org/project/views) to create a Page display that lists all your products.

Also, I haven't tried it myself, but here's a blog post on [Exposing Items Per Page in Drupal Views](http://bhavinahya.wordpress.com/2011/03/04/exposed-items-per-page-in-drupal-views/). A [patch has been committed to the 6.x-3.x version of Views](http://drupal.org/node/324092) that apparently offers a similar "items per page" select box.

Answer (score 0):

I second the suggestion to use Views.

I use it at Ubercart sites to do exactly what you ask.

I also have 'Taxonomy: Term Id' as one of the View Arguments, enabling term filtering in the URL. For example: expressions like '1,2,3' mean 'display all products with term ids 1 AND 2 AND 3' as well as expressions like '1+2+3' mean 'display all products with term ids 1 OR 2 OR 3'. Super useful. Plus I've marked 'all' to be the wildcard term, so displaying every product is the View URL with 'all' at the end.

You can see the semi-fancy result of this at a yet-under-construction site here:

http://www.cg-general-store.com/hdr_coverflow_panel/85

This is two Views with a form-block between them. Built using Panels and the Imageflow Views plugin. Both views, top and bottom, display the same info, controlled by taxonomy terms in the URL, with those terms controlled by the form-block simply doing to drupal_goto() back to the same page with the radio selections providing the term ids for the URL. All done with Views, Panels, and a little bit of custom FAPI.

Comment: Thank you, I'll be checking this out. Nice implementation!